# Do custom wrapper classes take more/less space than Java wrapper classes?

Tags: java, memory, wrapper

```
Public class A 
{
    int a;

}
```

vs.

java.lang.Integer

Or Longs, Doubles, etc.
Do they take the same amount of memory? Or more/less? If I'm not missing anything the answer should be same...

Comment: The wrapper class has it's own memory overheads, so it will increase the required amount of space needed to store it.

Comment: Your class is using instance of `Integer` so how is that suppose to take less space in total than `Integer`?

Comment: Can you comment on the differences? How much more memory should the former take compared to later?

Comment: @Pshemo sorry about that, should have been "int"

Comment: Your version won't support autoboxing or unboxing, so even if they take the same space they differ in functionality. Yours' also isn't `Comparable`, and it's lacking a `toString()`.

Comment: As a class Integer is larger (it contains more methods, and fields - mainly static ones), but instance of your class and Integer should take same space (they store only one field, which in your case is `a`, and for Integer is `value`). So since you are not saving any space I would say that creating new wrapper class is pointless (you are reducing number of methods and avoiding support for native wrapper classes).

Comment: Thanks guys! Just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the wrapper classes are to be able to treat a primitive as an object by wrapping it in an `Integer` object, allowing you to call methods from it, or pass it as a parameter value for parameters that require an `Object` rather than a primitive.

Creating your own wrapper for a primitive, such as you are doing now, is not advised, as it will **not allow for *auto*-boxing and unboxing of primitives**. There's more functionality you are losing, but if we're talking memory, you'll save more memory over-time using `Integer` rather than your personal wrapper, since **there is a constant pool for integer objects, allowing you to re-use a pre-existing value from the pool if one exists**, instead of creating a new object every time. You'd need to implement the *flyweight pattern* to achieve the same kind of memory-saving system.